# Token inválido JS

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tendo problemas com um projeto de calculadora feito em JS.
Em uma linha específica diz que foi encontrado um token inesperado. Já fui no Github do curso e verifiquei o arquivo final deles, e na linha onde no meu programa(uso o VisualCodeEstudio) aparece o erro, no outro programa que abri(Sublime) o código deles, tá sem erro algum..

Grato desde já!

```
class CalcController {

constructor(){
this._locale = 'pt-BR';
this._displayCalcEl = document.querySelector("#display");
this._dateEl = document.querySelector("#data");
this._timeEl = document.querySelector("#hora");
this._currentDate;
this.initialize();
this.initButtonsEvents();

}

initialize(){
   
this.setDisplayDateTime();

setInterval(()=>{

    this.setDisplayDateTime();

}, 1000);


addEventListenerAll(element, events, fn){

        events.split(' ').forEach(event => {

            element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);

        });


}

   




}

initButtonsEvents(){

    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#buttons > g, #parts > g") 
        
        buttons.forEach((btn, index)=>{

            this.addEventListenerAll(btn, "click drag", e=>{

                let textBtn = btn.className.baseVal.replace("btn-",""));
        
        
            });

            this.addEventListenerAll(btn, "mouseover mouseup mousedown", e=>{

                btn.style.cursor = "pointer";

            });

        });



}

setDisplayDateTime() {

    this.displayDate = this.currentDate.toLocaleDateString(this._locale,{
        day:"2-digit",
        month: "long",
        year:"numeric"

    });
    this.displayTime = this.currentDate.toLocaleTimeString(this._locale);



}

get displayTime(){
return this._timeEl.innerHTML;

}

set displayTime(valor){
    return this._timeEl.innerHTML = valor;
}


get displayDate(){
return this._dateEl.innerHTML;

}

set displayDate(valor){
    return this._dateEl.innerHTML = valor;
}


get displayCalc(){
    return this._displayCalcEl.innerHTML;
}

set displayCalc(valor){
    this._displayCalcEl.innerHTML = valor;
}

get currentDate(){
    return new Date();
}

set currentDate(valor){
    this._currentDate = valor;
}


}
```

[image: Print do projeto aberto no Chrome e do console mostrando o erro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você recebe esse erro apenas no VsCode porque ele deve estar configurado com EsLint, que te ajuda na indentificação de erros no código. O seu erro é de formatação e de sintaxe do JS, por isso o erro de token inválido.

```
class CalcController {
  constructor() {
    this._locale = "pt-BR";
    this._displayCalcEl = document.querySelector("#display");
    this._dateEl = document.querySelector("#data");
    this._timeEl = document.querySelector("#hora");
    this._currentDate;
    this.initialize();
    this.initButtonsEvents();
  }

  initialize() {
    this.setDisplayDateTime();

    setInterval(() => {
      this.setDisplayDateTime();
    }, 1000);
  }

  addEventListenerAll(element, events, fn) {
    events.split(" ").forEach(event => {
      element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    });
  }

  initButtonsEvents() {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#buttons > g, #parts > g");

    buttons.forEach((btn, index) => {
      this.addEventListenerAll(btn, "click drag", e => {
        let textBtn = btn.className.baseVal.replace("btn-", "");
      });

      this.addEventListenerAll(btn, "mouseover mouseup mousedown", e => {
        btn.style.cursor = "pointer";
      });
    });
  }

  setDisplayDateTime() {
    this.displayDate = this.currentDate.toLocaleDateString(this._locale, {
      day: "2-digit",
      month: "long",
      year: "numeric"
    });
    this.displayTime = this.currentDate.toLocaleTimeString(this._locale);
  }

  get displayTime() {
    return this._timeEl.innerHTML;
  }

  set displayTime(valor) {
    return (this._timeEl.innerHTML = valor);
  }

  get displayDate() {
    return this._dateEl.innerHTML;
  }

  set displayDate(valor) {
    return (this._dateEl.innerHTML = valor);
  }

  get displayCalc() {
    return this._displayCalcEl.innerHTML;
  }

  set displayCalc(valor) {
    this._displayCalcEl.innerHTML = valor;
  }

  get currentDate() {
    return new Date();
  }

  set currentDate(valor) {
    this._currentDate = valor;
  }
}
```

Sempre que receber esse erro de token inválido se atente a sintaxe da escrita do seu código e use os logs do eslint ao seu favor

Comment: Certo, eu refiz o código com base no que você me passou, e agora o erro mudou xD
No console do Chrome, aparece "Uncaught TypeError: this.addEventListenerAll is not a function at CalcController.js:30" , ou seja, o 'this.addeventlistener' diz que não é função..kkkkk

Comment: Eu editei o código, vê se funciona agora

Comment: Coloquei o seu código e milagrosamente funcionou! o/
Poderia me explicar o que estava errado desta outra vez? grato!

Comment: Faltavam ou sobravam alguns caracteres, como `}` e `)`. Coloque os dois códigos em paralelo e compare, você vai perceber